# NativeScript Angular - Top Action Bar in Master Detail

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have a problem with the Android version of an app I'm developing ...
I have list views with related detail pages ...
in the pages with listview I implement the navigation bar as follows:

```
<ActionBar class="actionclass" id="ActionBar" style="background-color:#ffffff ;">
<Image src="~/assets/images/XXXXX_Logo.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; height: 150px;"></Image>
</ActionBar>
```

the problem is in the detail view ... on iOS I have the arrow directly to back ... and ok ...

on android it remains white band with app name aligned to the left ... how can I customize? ... I tried to enter the code of the master page but it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

By default, the apps will rely on the soft buttons on Android. So typically the users will navigate back, home and between apps using these.

[image: soft buttons]

If you still want show a navigation button on Android, try to add it to the ActionBar ([see the documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#example-actionbar-with-navigationbutton)):

```
<ActionBar title="ActionBar Title">
  <NavigationButton text="Go back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" 
  tap="goBack" />
</ActionBar>
```